# Kayak Search / Data Aggregation Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search

Working on a project that is going to involve a similar sort of search algorithm to find the "cheapest price" of a certain commodity.

I was thinking a lot about this type of algorithm and how it may be implemented. At first, I thought that it was simply webscraping.

However, this seems unlikely. I think webscraping would take too long and would also cause more problems for websites that require you to interact with their API

How would I go about implementing this type of algorithm? I was thinking aggregating content into a database and then just running update checks on the data base to check if any prices have changed? Would this be a good way to go about it?

Comment: We'd need a lot more detail to go on I'm afraid. How many products do you want to search for the price of, or is it just one? Can you find enough places to search for that product online to web-scrape? It wouldn't take that long I would imagine. Obviously you can't search everywhere?

Comment: it involves searching for textbooks. So I would image i would be searching at least 10-20 websites at the minimum.It would be one textbook at a time, not multiple textbooks at once

Comment: If you have specific websites in mind then webscrape. Your database suggestion is just glossing over the problem of getting the prices - how do you populate your database. If you don't have specific websites in mind then make use of an [API for Shopping](https://www.semantics3.com/solutions/product-price-feed) and let them do all the hard work.